# How do I get ~/.bashrc to execute all scripts in my ~/Shell directory using a loop?

Tags: shell-script, bashrc, for

I have shell scripts in my `~/Shell` directory that I want to be run whenever Bash is started up as my usual user account. So what I have done is added the following to `~/.bashrc`:

```
for i in `find ~/Shell/ -name "*.sh"`
do
    sh $i
done
```

but, for whatever reason the functions contained in files with the file extension `.sh` in my `~/Shell` directory are not automatically loaded. For example, I have a function called `abash` in my `~/Shell/bash.sh` file and running `abash` from a new user terminal gave an error stating that the command was not found.

I know I can just manually list all the files in my `~/Shell` directory with a dot before them to get them executed at Bash startup time. For example, I used to have this in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```
. ~/Shell/bash.sh
. ~/Shell/cd.sh
. ~/Shell/emerge.sh
...
```

and it worked fine, but I would rather a `for` loop to do this, as it would mean if I add any new shell scripts to `~/Shell` I do not have to worry about adding them to `~/.bashrc`.

I have also now tried:

```
for i in `find -name "~/Shell/*.sh"`
do
        sh $i
done
```

and:

```
for i in "~/Shell/*.sh"
do
        sh $i
done
```

and:

```
for i in `find -name '~/Shell/*.sh'`
do
        sh $i
done
```

with no success.

Comment: for i in ~/Shell/*.sh do; . $i; done

Comment: Just gave that a try and it didn't work.

Comment: Don't execute it with sh; dot it in with .

Comment: Yes, although I decided to drop the `i` in `-iname` and use `.` instead of `source`. I did eventually drop his answer altogether and use Jeff's answer as it is simpler, but his answer worked with the adjustments I mentioned, at least. BinaryZebra (BZ)'s answer I find overly complex (I'm a programming noob tbh) and since I last saw it has become more complex and confusing. I think I'll accept your answer, now I think of it.

Comment: Glad you got a solution (and I see RobertL wrote it up); your answer had enough direction in it to solve your actual problem instead of focusing on the particular syntax you had been trying. BinaryZebra has some advanced shell usage that you can also learn from at your leisure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in your `.bashrc`:

```
for rc in ~/Shell/*.sh
do
    . "$rc"
done
```

And you're off to the races!

A couple of notes:

The `bash` (and `zsh` etc) `source` command, while readable, is not universal and does not exist in `dash`, the most posixly correct shell I know.  As it stands, this same code can be used to load code into almost any bourne-shell derivative.

The traditional naming convention for files to be directly sourced into the shell is to use a suffix of `rc` or `.rc` (as in `.bashrc`).  `rc` stands for "run commands". The `.sh` extension is usually used for executable script programs.  (These are *only* conventions -- not rules.)

Comment: The `~/Shell/*` will not include sub-directories (if used) under the directory `Shell`. It is similar but not equivalent to `find`.

Comment: You are correct.  By design.  `find` is overkill for this.  None of the OP examples contained subdirectories.  Plus, this answer helped you fix yours!  You should thank me!

Comment: Find is indeed very powerful, but that is what the user used and we should have an answer which is similar or note the differences (if any exist). That is the intent of my comment, to note the difference.

Comment: If that makes you feel happy, then: Many, many thanks to you!!

Answer (score 1):

Several issues:

- To work, the tilde needs to be un-quoted. Use $HOME, instead.
- To work, the * also needs to be un-quoted. Not needed for find.
- There should NOT be `/` in file names ("~/Shell/") for find.
- As files need to loaded and not executed, sh should be changed to source.

Try this:

```
for i in $(find "$HOME/Shell/" -iname "*.sh")
do 
    source "$i"
done
```

#### EDIT:

The option above could not process file names with spaces, newlines or problematic characters. To solve that we may use the full capacities of find, as this:

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    source "$file"
done < <(find "$HOME/Shell/" -name "*.sh" -type f -print0)
```

---

**NOTE:**

A solution with a simple asterisk `*` will not include sub-directories.

A complete solution using asterisks that will include sub-directories in the same manner as find just looks too complex:

```
resetextglob=$(shopt -p extglob)     # store value of extglob
resetnullglob=$(shopt -p nullglob)   # store value of nullglob

shopt +s extglob nullglob
for i in $HOME/Shell/*.sh $HOME/Shell/**/*.sh
do
    source "$i"
done

$resetextglob                        # reset extglob to original value
$resetnullglob                       # reset nullglob to original value
```

Comment: Just tried that, no errors came out but it didn't work as running `abash` from a new terminal tab after adding this to `~/.bashrc` returned: `bash: abash: command not found`

Comment: No, you mustn't have read my question properly -- `abash` is a **function** specified in `~/Shell/bash.sh`

Comment: Changed answer, changed bash (execution) to source (loading) of files.

Comment: This one won't work if script name contain space, tab, or newline, and required `find` implementation supported `-iname`.

Comment: @BinaryZebra: So please add a note. It's better to assume the OP only want one level, or at least using `**/*.sh` with `extglob` enable.

Comment: The `-iname` option of find will just allow for files that end in `.Sh` `.sH` `.SH` to also be accepted. Either do not name files with such extensions or use GNU compatible find (which seems reasonable as GNU bash is already being used).

Comment: @cuonglm Note(s) and solution(s) added.